# Reshape your data using array.reshape(-1, 1)

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, reshape

I am currently running multiple Linear Regression algorithms to run on the experimental data and then on the physical model and then compare the results. It works fine with experimental data but when I apply it to the Physical model I have errors.

As I am facing the error while doing the regression that is asking to reshape the data and when I go reshape the data I get an error, so basically I want to solve the reshaping error to solve the regression error

```
df = df[df['Battery'] == 'B0005'] # defining data frame 
df= df[df['Temperature_measured Celsius'] > 36] # choose battery B0005
#df['Time Secs'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Secs''], unit='s')
dfb = df.groupby(['id_cycle']).max() # grouping data frame by max. number of  id_cycle 
dfb['Cumulated_T'] = dfb['Time Secs'].cumsum() # returning  cumulative sum over df = time 

from math import e
L = (dfb['Capacity']-dfb['Capacity'].iloc[0:1].values[0])/-dfb['Capacity'].iloc[0:1].values[0]
print(L)
K = 0.13
L_1 = 1-e**(-K*dfb.index*dfb['Temperature_measured Celsius']/(dfb['Time Secs']))
print(L_1)
dfb['C. Capacity'] = -(L_1*dfb['Capacity'].iloc[0:1].values[0]) + dfb['Capacity'].iloc[0:1].values[0]
print(dfb['C. Capacity'])

M = pd.DataFrame()
S = pd.DataFrame()
def MAE(M,S):    
    return np.sum(S-M)/len(S) 
print(f'Mean Absolute Error =', round(MAE(dfb['Capacity'], dfb['C. Capacity']), 3))

X_in = dfb['C. Capacity']       # input: the simulation time series
print(X_in)
X_out = dfb['Capacity'] - dfb['C. Capacity']   # output: difference between measurement and simulation
print(X_out)


X_in_train, X_in_test, X_out_train, X_out_test = train_test_split(X_in, X_out, test_size=0.33)

X_in_train.shape
print(X_in_train)
id_cycle
82     1.595281
27     1.782309
63     1.668317
116    1.457604
96     1.543814
         ...   
144    1.347684
2      1.850850
70     1.642051
104    1.511860
152    1.327572
Name: C. Capacity, Length: 112, dtype: float64

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_in_train, X_out_train)
#print(regressor.intercept_)
```

Regression Error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-f68beec386b3> in <module>
      1 regressor = LinearRegression()
----> 2 regressor.fit(X_in_train, X_out_train)
      3 #print(regressor.intercept_)

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    516         accept_sparse = False if self.positive else ['csr', 'csc', 'coo']
    517 
--> 518         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
    519                                    y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
    520 

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    431                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    432             else:
--> 433                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    434             out = X, y
    435 

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    812         raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
    813 
--> 814     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
    815                     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
    816                     dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy,

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    635             # If input is 1D raise error
    636             if array.ndim == 1:
--> 637                 raise ValueError(
    638                     "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray={}.\n"
    639                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1.59528055 1.78230941 1.66831671 1.45760392 1.54381385 1.79328362
 1.27303894 1.67315206 1.3055509  1.56047996 1.41807866 1.44230597
 1.69396075 1.66576663 1.28082621 1.45417475 1.7327256  1.33726311
 1.33791544 1.68280547 1.31392396 1.28396927 1.37185045 1.52187777
 1.80164823 1.44830955 1.78510329 1.66069893 1.53077649 1.63805139
 1.46087027 1.71381009 1.72708647 1.35146193 1.36681081 1.50570233
 1.28851117 1.85368421 1.40513749 1.50150899 1.67977885 1.32282875
 1.83682695 1.77361434 1.53521689 1.75391431 1.83126747 1.51767451
 1.71143867 1.52632168 1.83965243 1.61340173 1.47567043 1.59079438
 1.71610293 1.64990921 1.37862044 1.82273931 1.80884748 1.2927751
 1.80591543 1.74441648 1.29700559 1.55666227 1.58704868 1.75657106
 1.5787517  1.64591411 1.27682509 1.84247348 1.44493345 1.32835169
 1.62650759 1.44856546 1.84524168 1.39309549 1.34204257 1.40133418
 1.77659414 1.80307737 1.82850378 1.84803047 1.70022893 1.33241491
 1.63460269 1.72321509 1.31845604 1.7720343  1.78780916 1.83405072
 1.41435281 1.51597232 1.38169973 1.30930752 1.58083407 1.34466753
 1.65707969 1.43604011 1.49634318 1.73540419 1.41037658 1.30141797
 1.81446833 1.56640665 1.68686215 1.57005619 1.79584333 1.34768412
 1.8508504  1.64205117 1.51185953 1.32757228].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

When Reshaping the X_in_train

```
reshaped_to_2d = np.reshape(X_in_train, (-1, 1), order='F') 
print(reshaped_to_2d)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-37ed567606dc> in <module>
----> 1 reshaped_to_2d = np.reshape(X_in_train, (-1, 1), order='F')
      2 print(reshaped_to_2d)

<__array_function__ internals> in reshape(*args, **kwargs)

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in reshape(a, newshape, order)
    297            [5, 6]])
    298     """
--> 299     return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
    300 
    301 

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     53     bound = getattr(obj, method, None)
     54     if bound is None:
---> 55         return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 
     57     try:

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     46         if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):
     47             result = asarray(result)
---> 48         result = wrap(result)
     49     return result
     50 

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array_wrap__(self, result, context)
   1927             return result
   1928         d = self._construct_axes_dict(self._AXIS_ORDERS, copy=False)
-> 1929         return self._constructor(result, **d).__finalize__(
   1930             self, method="__array_wrap__"
   1931         )

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    362                     data = data.copy()
    363             else:
--> 364                 data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True)
    365 
    366                 data = SingleBlockManager.from_array(data, index)

D:\Programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
    527     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
    528         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
--> 529             raise ValueError("Data must be 1-dimensional")
    530         else:
    531             subarr = com.asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error message that you quote a) does not match your question title; b) is not [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146). Please fix this.

Comment: Thank you , What exactly do you want me to fix? As I am facing the error while doing the regression that is asking to reshape the data and when I go reshape the data I get an error of the one I quote, so basically I want to solve the reshaping error to solve the regression error

Comment: "What exactly do you want me to fix?" I want you to copy and paste the complete error message, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, formatted as code; and I want you to make sure that the title of your question reflects that error message (rather than having mismatching numbers). Do you see the `Edit` link under your post? You should use that to edit the post, rather than adding information in the comments.